# How to put several views(not images) in page view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am a very starter in iOS Developing.

Now I would like to make an app of a children's story book using PageViewController. I have read some tutorials of PageViewController, but unfortunately all of them are about putting images in the PageContentViewController. I want to use views instead of images, because the content will be modified sometimes. Also, I don't want the views overlapped together because I want the workflow be visible.

I wonder whether there is a way to achieve it??? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you talking about code or Interface Builder?

Comment: I want both!!!  -.-|||

Comment: It works precisely as those other tutorials you referenced undoubtedly describe. Just don't put image views in those view controller scenes, but rather put whatever you want there. Frankly, when I searched the web for `UIPageViewController` tutorial, the very first one I found didn't use image views. I'd suggest you search again and you'll find tutorials that work with standard view controllers, not just those with only image views on them. There are tons of good tutorials out there.